# Image Processing (OpenCV with PHP) - Issue with the exec command

Tags: php, python, c++, opencv, simplecv

I have setup OpenCV 3.0 with python3.4 binding on ubuntu 14.04. I run OpenCV using virtualenv. So, everytime I have to run the `workon cv` command.

Now I want to run a python script that uses OpenCV library from PHP using the `exec` command.

```
exec("workon cv");
exec("python3 hough_circles.py")
```

This is the error :

```
sh: 1: workon: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hough_circles.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues...

**1. PATH to workon**

The error message is telling you it doesn't know where `workon` is, so you better tell it the full path to where it is so `exec()` can find it, e.g.:

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/workon cv");
```

The `/usr/local/bin` above is just an example, if you want to know where it is on your system, run:

```
which workon
```

and use the output.

**2. Subprocesses are independent**

Even when you have got that set correctly, the process that executes `workon` then exits and you start a fresh, shiny new one - in which you have not run `workon`. So, you better do both things in the same process like this:

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/workon cv && /path/to/python3 hough_circles.py");
```